# Problema al recibir el Body en NodeJS desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Como envio el fetch al backend

```js
onSubmit (e) {
        var random = stringGen(6);
        e.preventDefault();
        let details = new FormData();
        details.append('demo_id', random);
        details.append('description', this.state.description);
        details.append('url', this.state.url);

      
        fetch (backend+`/api/demos/create/details`, {
          method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: details
    })
        .then(() => {
          location.reload();
        });
      }
```

Como llega en el backend el `req.body`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que llegue como un simple json

Algo como esto

```js
{
   dato : valor,
   dato : valor
}
```

Comment: Asi es, en el express de la API lo tengo eso y no funciona

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `FormData`? ¿Estás enviando info binaria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, sé consecuente con lo que deseas hacer. Si vas a enviar datos **no binarios**, utiliza JSON; en otro caso, utiliza `FormData` para enviar datos binarios como objetos `File`.

Si el caso es que quieres enviar datos binarios y además valores estándar, en este caso necesitarías usar [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). Multer te permite además, obtener los otros datos que no son binarios por medio de `fields()`:

```
router.post('/tu-url', upload.fields(), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body); // disponible los campos estándar
});
```

En los demás casos, envía un JSON:

> Es necesario enviar el JSON como string.

```
fetch (backend+`/api/demos/create/details`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      demo_id: random,
      description: this.state.description,
      url: this.state.url
    })
});
```

**Nota:** recuerda añadir `bodyParser` para que Express parsee los JSON y los `FormData`:

```
// para urlencoded data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Eso comente en lo último, faltaba el stringify. Ahi la edite

Answer (score 2):

Si queres que llegue como un JSON, deberías construir un JSON en primer lugar.

```
var details = {
    demo_id: random,
    decription: this.state.description,
    url: this.state.url
};
```

Luego, deberías envíarlo como "application/json":

```
fetch (backend+`/api/demos/create/details`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(details)
})
```

Suponiendo que el resto este bien (backend), debería andar.

Si no queres modificar la manera en la que envías el formulario, podes agregar el body-parser con express:
[Link a Github](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

Comment: Intente como dices pero ahora req.body esta vacio. Me sale body: {}

Comment: Y tienes el middleware bodyparser?

Comment: Tenes que agregar el middleware body-parser para que automaticamente parsee las respuestas a JSON

Comment: Si lo tengo, es mas si hago esto pero por postman me devuelve el json perfectamente. Tengo el bodyParser en el server de la api 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

Comment: Por lo que vi la forma de que lleguen los datos a la api es usando headers application/x-www-form-urlencoded de las otras formas que intente como application/json me devuelve un body vacio

Comment: Proba: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data

Comment: Si queres usar application/json deberías stringify el body, ese es el problema me parece:

body: JSON.stringify(details)

Comment: Gracias Ariel, funciono lo de usar application/json y JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

agrega la linea en tu archivo app de Nodejs la siguiente linea:

app.use(bodyParser.json());

,siempre y cuando uses express y body-parser
(
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
)